# Coverage map display using .adf files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-coverage-format

I am trying to load a coverage map onto Arcgis for desktop using .adf files that I downloaded from a county supported filezilla server. I am not experienced with coverage maps, however I have reason to believe that I do not have all the files needed to form a coverage map. When I try to search for the map using catalog nothing shows up and when I tried to import the files using data interoperability and it said that there was no geometry (however I could be using this tool wrong). I have uploaded a picture of the files that I downloaded, am I missing some files, or am I just misunderstanding the use of coverage map format? [image]

Answer (score 1):

A Coverage can have a series of folders as well as a number of files.  There is **ALWAYS** an **`info`** folder as well as other folders of coverage files.

There must be no spaces anywhere in your pathnames - something like `c:\my documents\coverages` won't work because of the space in `my documents` - and everything must be lowercase.

Check out the ArcGIS Desktop Help page on [**Contents of a Coverage Workspace**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/coverages/contents-of-a-coverage-workspace.htm) to double check that you've got all the files and folders you need.

From the looks of the files in your screenshot you don't have all the files you require to recreate the Coverage.